# How can I hide my stack frames in a TestCase subclass?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, subclass, stack-trace

I want to add a custom assert method to a `TestCase` subclass.  I tried to copy my implementation from the `unittest` module so that it would match the behaviour of the regular `TestCase` as closely as possible.  (I would prefer to just delegate to `self.assertEqual()` but this causes even more backtrace noise, see below.)  The `unittest` module seems to automatically hide some internal details of its implementation when reporting failed assertions.

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertLengthIsOne(self, sequence, msg=None):
        if len(sequence) != 1:
            msg = self._formatMessage(msg, "length is not one")
            raise self.failureException(msg)

class TestFoo(MyTestCase):
    seq = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    def test_stock_unittest_assertion(self):
        self.assertEqual(len(self.seq), 1)

    def test_custom_assertion(self):
        self.assertLengthIsOne(self.seq)


unittest.main()
```

The output of this is as such:

```
amoe@vuurvlieg $ python unittest-demo.py
FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_custom_assertion (__main__.TestFoo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unittest-demo.py", line 16, in test_custom_assertion
    self.assertLengthIsOne(self.seq)
  File "unittest-demo.py", line 7, in assertLengthIsOne
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: length is not one

======================================================================
FAIL: test_stock_unittest_assertion (__main__.TestFoo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unittest-demo.py", line 13, in test_stock_unittest_assertion
    self.assertEqual(len(self.seq), 1)
AssertionError: 5 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Note that the custom assert method causes a stack trace with two frames, one inside the method itself, whereas the stock `unittest` method only has one frame, the relevant line in the user's code.  How can I apply this frame-hiding behaviour to my own method?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This question was answered [by Peter Otten on comp.lang.python](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-October/632388.html).

Move MyTestCase in a separate module and define a global variable `__unittest = True`.

```
$ cat mytestcase.py 
import unittest

__unittest = True

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertLengthIsOne(self, sequence, msg=None):
        if len(sequence) != 1:
            msg = self._formatMessage(msg, "length is not one")
            raise self.failureException(msg)

$ cat mytestcase_demo.py 
import unittest
from mytestcase import MyTestCase

class TestFoo(MyTestCase):
    seq = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    def test_stock_unittest_assertion(self):
        self.assertEqual(len(self.seq), 1)

    def test_custom_assertion(self):
        self.assertLengthIsOne(self.seq)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

$ python mytestcase_demo.py 
FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_custom_assertion (__main__.TestFoo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytestcase_demo.py", line 11, in test_custom_assertion
    self.assertLengthIsOne(self.seq)
AssertionError: length is not one

======================================================================
FAIL: test_stock_unittest_assertion (__main__.TestFoo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytestcase_demo.py", line 8, in test_stock_unittest_assertion
    self.assertEqual(len(self.seq), 1)
AssertionError: 5 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=2)
$
```

Comment: I cannot believe this question/answer have not received more votes! Great information & exactly why I <3 SO.

Comment: This solution is so helpful!

Comment: Not sure if the pipermail on python.org changed but the correct link to Peter's solution is https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-October/632386.html . Other than that thank you very much for the pointer, really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.11 there still isn't a public api to hide helper assert methods in the stack frame. Setting `__unittest` still works but I want to hide my custom assert methods with more flexibility. So I monkeypatch `TestResult._remove_unittest_tb_frames` to remove the assert_* and following frames from the stack trace.

The decorator sets a variable to True inside the wrapper function. The monkeypatched method we create checks for that variable and if found truncates the current and following tb nodes.

There are two tests. One with the `@helper_assert` decorator and the other without

```
$ python -m unittest hide_assert_helpers
before: test_with_verbose_stack -> assertTruthy2 -> nested_func
after : test_with_verbose_stack -> assertTruthy2 -> nested_func

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hide_assert_helpers.py", line 80, in test_with_verbose_stack
    self.assertTruthy2("")
  File "hide_assert_helpers.py", line 64, in assertTruthy2
    nested_func()
  File "hide_assert_helpers.py", line 62, in nested_func
    raise AssertionError("Value '{}' does not evaluate to True".format(val))
AssertionError: Value '' does not evaluate to True

before: test_without_verbose_stack -> wrapper -> assertTruthy -> nested_func
after : test_without_verbose_stack

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hide_assert_helpers.py", line 76, in test_without_verbose_stack
    self.assertTruthy("")
AssertionError: Value '' does not evaluate to True
```

```
# hide_assert_helpers.py
from unittest import TestCase


# Remove helper assert methods from stack trace
def helper_assert(func):
    from functools import wraps
    from unittest import TestResult

    # print tb linked list
    def debug_print_linked_tb(tb, prefix=""):
        tb_list = []
        while tb:
            tb_list.append(tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_name)
            tb = tb.tb_next
        print(prefix + " -> ".join(tb_list))

    if not globals().get("_remove_unittest_tb_frames_setup"):
        globals()["_remove_unittest_tb_frames_setup"] = True
        _remove_unittest_tb_frames_copy = getattr(
            TestResult, "_remove_unittest_tb_frames"
        )

        def _remove_unittest_tb_frames_new(self_obj, tb):
            _remove_unittest_tb_frames_copy(self_obj, tb)

            debug_print_linked_tb(tb, prefix="before: ")

            tb_prev = None
            tb_curr = tb
            while tb_curr:
                is_decorator = tb_curr.tb_frame.f_locals.get(
                    "__unittest_helper_decorator"
                )

                # tb is a linked list
                # remove all nodes at and after @helper_assert decorator
                # we can technically splice middle frames and leave remaining if we want
                if is_decorator:
                    tb_prev.tb_next = None
                    break

                tb_prev = tb_curr
                tb_curr = tb_curr.tb_next

            debug_print_linked_tb(tb, prefix="after : ")

        setattr(
            TestResult, "_remove_unittest_tb_frames", _remove_unittest_tb_frames_new
        )

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        __unittest_helper_decorator = True
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class StackOverflowTestCase(TestCase):
    def assertTruthy2(self, val):
        def nested_func():
            if not val:
                raise AssertionError("Value '{}' does not evaluate to True".format(val))

        nested_func()

    @helper_assert
    def assertTruthy(self, val):
        def nested_func():
            if not val:
                raise AssertionError("Value '{}' does not evaluate to True".format(val))

        nested_func()

    def test_without_verbose_stack(self):
        self.assertTruthy("foo")
        self.assertTruthy("")

    def test_with_verbose_stack(self):
        self.assertTruthy2("foo")
        self.assertTruthy2("")
```